# COALESCE and ARRAY in postgresql - query

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, where-clause, sql-null

I'd like to use an array as a filter in the query, but also, I need to return all values if no values were provided (by preparedStatement - java).

Something like this:

```sql
AND column = any(coalesce(?, column_example::text[]))
```

The problem is that column_example is a varchar column. How to achieve this need with sql (postgres) ?

Version:

PostgreSQL 11.9 (Ubuntu 11.9-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0, 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to return all values if no values were provided

You could just do:

```
AND ( ? is null or column = any(?::text[]) )
```

The casting of the parameter to an array might not be necessary, depending on whether your driver is able to properly pass such datatype. If so:

```
AND ( ? is null or column = any(?) )
```

Comment: With this small change -> AND ( ?::text[] is null or column = any(?::text[]) ) the query worked. I am using org.postgresql.Driver from Jdbc.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . how about two separate comparisons?

```
AND
(column = ? OR ? IS NULL AND column = any(column_example::text[]))
```

You need to pass the parameter in twice or use a named parameter.

Comment: This did not work for me because the column is a varchar, but I'd like to pass an array argument. Also, this gave me the error: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "test"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
SQL state: 22P02